# Cakephp Model Validation decimal value

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to validate a decimal value, i do use naturalNumber but did not recognize a value as 1,00 as greater than zero.

How can i work with decimal values using Cakephp 2 validation ? (0,01) would be accepted!

I try :

```
$this->loadModel('SomeModel');    
$data = array(
    'decimal_value' => '0,01',
); 

$this->SomeModel->save($data);

class SomeModel extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
            'naturalNumber' => array(
                'rule' => 'naturalNumber',
                'message' => 'Value must be grater than 0',
                'required' => true
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: without knowing cakephp 2 validation.. 0,01 is not a natural number. also possibly you need to use a dot instead of comma for decimals. commas are to separate thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimals aren't natural numbers, natural numbers do not have fractions. Also `0,01` doesn't validate, `Validation::naturalNumber('0,01')` returns `false`.

If you want to validate decimals, use for example the `decimal` rule (and if you do make sure that you set the proper locale if you expect commas as decimal separator), or even a custom regex.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Data Validation > Validation::decimal()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::decimal)**
- **[PHP Manual > setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)**